# Checking to see if cmd shutdown command restarted remote computer on windows 7

Tags: batch-file, cmd, remote-desktop

I am in the process of creating a batch file that will restart a remote computer then log me back in once the computer has finished restarting.  I have everything working except error handling.  All I need is to check to see if my shutdown was successful or failed.

Here is the part of my code where I need help:

```
@echo off
set /p Computer=Restart which computer? 
shutdown -r -m %Computer% -f -t 0
```

I need to detect if the last line executed successfully or not.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit:

Problem solved.  Final code below.

```
@echo off
set DateTime=%Date% %Time%
set Comment=Comment: %DateTime%
set /p Computer=Restart which computer? 
REM Check to see if targeted computer is currently online
ping -n 1 -w 500 %Computer% | find "TTL"
if errorlevel 1 GOTO Error1
cls
shutdown -r -m %Computer% -f -t 0 -c "%DateTime%
REM Checking to make sure shut down was successful
timeout /t 2 /nobreak
wevtutil qe system /q:*[System[EventID=1074]] /c:1 /f:text /rd:true /r:%Computer% | find "%Comment%"
if errorlevel 1 GOTO Error2
```

Thanks to Kayasax for pointing me to wevtutil.

Thanks to James L. for starting me down the path to adding the date and time in the comment to make sure it was the most recent reboot.

Comment: If a reboot does occur, your batch file will **stop** running...  So you will have to run another process when you finish rebooting to log in, right?  Is that when you want to check to see if the computer rebooted?

Comment: @JamesL. A batch file on the **local** computer won't stop running when a **remote** computer reboots.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Yes, of course you are right!

Comment: glad i had helped you. I think you have a typo in your update it should be shutdown -r -m %Computer% -f -t 0 -c "%Comment%"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try to query the eventlog of the remote computer and check for eventid 6005 example with the wevtutil utility from windows7

```
wevtutil qe system /q:*[System[EventID=6005]] /c:1 /f:text /rd:true /r %Computer%
```

Comment: You might find it useful to convert the date/time from wevtutil to Julian values to verify the reboot was done **today**.  These conversion routines are very handy: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsDateTime.php

Comment: Thank you!  This wasn't quite what I needed, but it led me down the right path.